# Can jenkins report on history with jUnit and nUnit test output in a single Project

Tags: junit, msbuild, jenkins, continuous-integration, nunit

I have an ASP .NET MVC project that is built in a Jenkins project. We're using the nUnit plugin to fangle the output from our unit tests as a post-build step.

I've just added Jasmine tests for the javascript in the project and added a step in MSBuild to have Chutzpah run the Jasmine tests and output the results in jUnit format.

[image: post-build-steps]

I added a post build step to process the jUnit results file and Jenkins runs the build and presents two 'Test Results' links in the Build result page...

[image: build-result]

However, when I click those links both go to the same result. When I left yesterday it was the nUnit results this morning it's the jUnit results so I'm guessing that it's just whichever finished last?

Is this possible? Do I need to do things a different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try just using the [xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) plugin, that way you can configure it to take bothe the junit and nunit test results all in a single publisher.

Comment: Just a warning to anyone else reading this, xUnit is a lot more picky with validating your jUnit results xml file, I got a parsing error with xUnit that I wasn't before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Jenkins related to this: [NUnit Plugin fails to merge Unit test reports with unit tests split on basis of category](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4872).

To get around this, just put your NUnit post build action as the last that it works!